# Pandas wide to long bringing empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was working in a pretty simple task: applying `wide_to_long` to a DataFrame, but every time I ran it, I got an empty DataFrame. I was almost sure I was doing it the right way, so I went to the documentation and tried to apply the example shown there, and it also brought an empty DataFrame! This is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'famid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'birth': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'ht_one': [2.8, 2.9, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 2.1],
    'ht_two': [3.4, 3.8, 2.9, 3.2, 2.8, 2.4, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9]
})

l = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='ht', i=['famid', 'birth'], j='age', sep='_', suffix='\\w')
l.shape
```

Output:

```
Out[2]: (0, 3)
```

I tried updating Pandas, but it didn't help. What could be happening?

Comment: change to `suffix='\\w+'
` missing + here

Answer (score 5):

That dataframe is the same used in Pandas' official documentation on [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long).

For this specific case, that have non-integers as suffixes, use `suffix=r'\w+'`,

```
l = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='ht', i=['famid', 'birth'], j='age',
                    sep='_', suffix=r'\w+')
```

And if one prints the shape of `l`, one gets the following

```
print(l.shape)
[Out]: (18, 1)
```

Or, as [@BENY suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435021/pandas-wide-to-long-bringing-empty-dataframe#comment99464281_56435021), `suffix='\\w+'`

```
l = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='ht', i=['famid', 'birth'], j='age',
                    sep='_', suffix='\\w+')
```

And if one prints the shape of `l` one gets the following

```
print(l.shape)
[Out]: (18, 1)
```